TimescaleDB query occasionally VERY slow
We're using TimescaleDB in an IoT environment, so doing quite a lot of inserts with no issues. In this case however, we're seeing this particular SELECT query sometimes be very slow (10-15 seconds), even in the QA environment with very low load. The normal execution time is around 400ms (across VPN using pgAdmin).
This is the query, where the parameters of course will vary for each call:
SELECT 
t.time :: timestamp + '60 minutes' :: INTERVAL, 
t.data ->> 'gfdm:LEVEL', 
t.data ->>  ''
FROM q_telemetry.telemetry_data 
WHERE device_twin_id = '3de7116b-e04b-446b-af8e-51a579222423' 
AND data ? 'gfdm:LEVEL'
AND time >= '2024-06-14T01:00' :: timestamp 
AND time < '2024-06-14T07:00' :: timestamp 
ORDER BY time

This is the SQL of the table creation (using create script in pgAdmin):
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS q_telemetry.telemetry_data
(
    device_twin_id uuid NOT NULL,
    "time" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    write_time timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    data jsonb NOT NULL,
    type q_telemetry.telemetry_type
)

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_telemetry_data
    ON q_telemetry.telemetry_data USING gin
    (data)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_telemetry_devicetwinid_time
    ON q_telemetry.telemetry_data USING btree
    (device_twin_id ASC NULLS LAST, "time" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS telemetry_data_time_idx
    ON q_telemetry.telemetry_data USING btree
    ("time" DESC NULLS FIRST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE TRIGGER ts_insert_blocker
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON q_telemetry.telemetry_data
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION _timescaledb_internal.insert_blocker();

These are the results from running query analyzes in pgAdmin:


I'm not knowledgable enough to determine if that looks optimal or not, and could use some input and improvement suggestions.
EDIT Here is the detailed EXPLAIN output as requested:
"Sort  (cost=3679.43..3681.49 rows=825 width=80) (actual time=6.058..6.077 rows=358 loops=1)"
"  Output: (((t.""time"")::timestamp without time zone + '01:00:00'::interval)), ((t.data ->> 'gfdm:LEVEL'::text)), ((t.data ->> ''::text)), t.""time"""
"  Sort Key: t.""time"""
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 52kB"
"  Buffers: shared hit=158"
"  ->  Custom Scan (ChunkAppend) on q_telemetry.telemetry_data t  (cost=0.28..3639.47 rows=825 width=80) (actual time=1.966..5.969 rows=358 loops=1)"
"        Output: ((t.""time"")::timestamp without time zone + '01:00:00'::interval), (t.data ->> 'gfdm:LEVEL'::text), (t.data ->> ''::text), t.""time"""
"        Startup Exclusion: true"
"        Runtime Exclusion: false"
"        Chunks excluded during startup: 820"
"        Buffers: shared hit=158"
"        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on _timescaledb_internal._hyper_7_3288_chunk t_1  (cost=86.72..96.72 rows=5 width=528) (actual time=1.948..3.418 rows=358 loops=1)"
"              Output: t_1.""time"", t_1.data"
"              Recheck Cond: ((t_1.device_twin_id = '3de7116b-e04b-446b-af8e-51a579222423'::uuid) AND (t_1.""time"" >= '2024-06-14 01:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (t_1.""time"" < '2024-06-14 07:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (t_1.data ? 'gfdm:LEVEL'::text))"
"              Heap Blocks: exact=118"
"              Buffers: shared hit=158"
"              ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=86.72..86.72 rows=5 width=0) (actual time=1.919..1.920 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=40"
"                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on _hyper_7_3288_chunk_idx_telemetry_devicetwinid_time  (cost=0.00..13.43 rows=401 width=0) (actual time=0.079..0.079 rows=360 loops=1)"
"                          Index Cond: ((t_1.device_twin_id = '3de7116b-e04b-446b-af8e-51a579222423'::uuid) AND (t_1.""time"" >= '2024-06-14 01:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (t_1.""time"" < '2024-06-14 07:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=6"
"                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on _hyper_7_3288_chunk_idx_telemetry_data  (cost=0.00..73.04 rows=2005 width=0) (actual time=1.833..1.833 rows=14603 loops=1)"
"                          Index Cond: (t_1.data ? 'gfdm:LEVEL'::text)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=34"
"Settings: effective_cache_size = '24GB', jit = 'off', random_page_cost = '2'"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=32363"
"Planning Time: 258.666 ms"
"Execution Time: 15.872 ms"


Is this the scenario that it's slow?
Have you thought about the cache hit ratio of your db? It maybe the times that it's not cached and then it needs to go to disk to find some information.  Is this search related to another time frame not often searched? Did you observe any pattern in the queries?

Could you please share the results from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for your SQL statement? In plain text

Those images strip out all the information that would actually be useful.  You need to make sure the plans were run with ANALYZE and BUFFERS, and post the results as text (not images, not JSON) formatted so as to preserve indenting and newlines.  Also, we need to see the plan from when the query is slow, not only a plan from when it was fast.  If you can't reproduce the slow query at will to get the plan, then auto_explain can help with that.

Thanks for your comments! Re. the timeframe: It is almost always within the same day that data is queried, i.e. give me data from the last six hours.
Re. proper EXPLAIN output: I've added this to the post now.
Re. slow query execution plan: I can't reproduce on demand unfortunately, so this is from a fast execution, and maybe therefore not helpful. I'll look into auto explain, didn't know about that!
